# Emacs org-mode agenda filtering not working

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs version 24.3 on Aquamacs and org-mode version 8.3beta.

I would like to filter by tags.

My file looks like:

```
* TODO a todo item     :header:
```

I use the `C-a m` command and type `header` into the prompt.

I get back

```
Headlines with TAGS match: header
Press `C-u r' to search again with new search string
```

With no body.

I have also tried this on a windows machine, and on the emacs distributed with my mac (`/usr/bin/emacs`) with the same result. I have tried searching with quotes, with colons, etc, but get the same result.

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: As a test to see whether your installation is set up correctly, is tags auto-completion working when using `M-x org-sparse-tree` and the `m`atch option?

Comment: Yes, `M-x org-sparse-tree` with the `m` option appears to have worked correctly.

Comment: If you are able to use tab auto-completion when using `M-x org-sparse-tree` and the `m`atch option, then I see no reason why you would not be able to display the body of all headers containing those tags.  I'm out of ideas then, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, it's been frustrating. Luckily, the `M-x org-sparse-tree` fulfills my needs pretty well (I didn't know about it before)! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your org file has not been added to the list that is scanned when an agenda is made.  You add your file to the list with C-c [, and then try using C-a m and typing in your tag.